# Performance Counter Interfering With Others

Tags: c#, windows, performancecounter

I need to define performance counters for an application. I wrote couple of unit tests to assure they are working as expected. I have a test class for each different counter type like AverageCounterTest (`AverageCount64`) or InstantaneousCounterTest (`NumberOfItems64`) or RateCounterTest (`RateOfCountsPerSecond64`). When I run them separately they pass. If I run them together, most of them fail due to counters reporting `0` values.

Tests are as simple as the following for `NumberOfItems64`:

```
counter.NextValue(); // sample first and reset the counter
int someValue = random.Next(int.MaxValue);
counter.IncrementBy(someValue);
float expected = someValue;
Assert.AreEqual(expected, counter.NextValue());
```

Another example could be for `RateOfCountsPerSecond64`:

```
counter.NextValue(); // sample first and reset the counter
counter.IncrementBy(1);
Thread.Sleep(2000);
float expected = 1 / (float)2;
Assert.IsTrue(expected, counter.NextValue());
```

What might be causing counters report `0`s? I use different performance counter categories per test (random Guid) to isolate them.

Comment: How / when are you creating the performance counters for the tests?